# (Non-typical) Can’t create table ‘dbnamehere.catalog_category_flat_store_1’

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, indexing

I have spent the past three days combing the internet for a resolve to this issue. I seriously need help because it seems so non-typical. Anything offered is very much appreciated.

Running CE 1.8

Fresh installation of 1.8, installed a solid 1.8 theme with high reviews. All indexing worked fine.
As soon as I add a category, Product Flat Data and Category Flat Data will no longer index.

I have all folder and SQL permissions correct. I’ve cleared locks and ran every SQL query I can find with no luck. And yes I’ve imported the database after trying a bunch of things as not to dig this whole deeper. Below is the the exception.log’s 2 errors.

```
2014-03-26T23:25:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'dbname_db_user.#sql-2492_2f3a69d' (errno: 121)
Trace: #0 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo-&gt;_execute(Array)
#2 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;_execute(Array)
#3 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement-&gt;execute(Array)
#4 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2731): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(815): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;reindexAll()
#11 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;reindexAll()
#12 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat-&gt;reindexAll()
#13 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process-&gt;reindexAll()
#14 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process-&gt;reindexEverything()
#15 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController-&gt;reindexProcessAction()
#16 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-&gt;dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-&gt;match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-&gt;dispatch()
#19 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;run(Array)
#20 /home1/dbname/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
2014-03-26T23:25:54+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'dbname_db_user.#sql-2492_2f3a8ee' (errno: 121)
Trace: #0 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo-&gt;_execute(Array)
#2 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;_execute(Array)
#3 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement-&gt;execute(Array)
#4 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /home1/dbname/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2731): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(815): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-&gt;addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;reindexAll()
#11 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer-&gt;reindexAll()
#12 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat-&gt;reindexAll()
#13 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process-&gt;reindexAll()
#14 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process-&gt;reindexEverything()
#15 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController-&gt;reindexProcessAction()
#16 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-&gt;dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-&gt;match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-&gt;dispatch()
#19 /home1/dbname/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;run(Array)
#20 /home1/dbname/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Turning flat products/categories off allows it to index. Back on comes back to this.
My new categories consist of 1 root and 6 sub. No products in any of them.   Also, one thing that seems odd is that the following query says the table doesn't exists.

```
truncate table catalog_category_flat_store_1;
```

Thank you VERY much in advance for ANY help. I will be quick to respond.

Answer (score 0):

What is your default engine set to? The most common reason for this error in older mysql versions and when migrating a db from one host to another is that the engine is set to myisam when it should be InnoDb.

Comment: My host's default engine is set to MyISAM. I tried to run the query below in phpMyAdmin to change those tables to InnoDB, but receive "Empty value in the form!"  Sorry but I can't seem to inlay code in the comment.

ET @DATABASE_NAME = 'db_name';

SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ENGINE=InnoDB;') AS sql_statements
FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
WHERE   table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME
AND     `ENGINE` = 'MyISAM'
AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name DESC;

Comment: you could do it manually or with a php script that loops for each table with `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = INNODB;` or drop it and make sure its innodb when re-importing

Comment: Christoffer,When I log into phpMyAdmin and view the db structure, the column named "type" shows "InnoDB" for all tables except for these 4: #__catalogsearch_fulltext,
#__oauth_nonce,
catalogsearch_fulltext,
auth_nonce,

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate solution:

In the DB I had to change table_prefix

```
"#__"
```

to

```
"customname_"
```